# Parallel while loop

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
private void Synchronize()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            SyncRequests();

            SyncIncidents();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

this is an infinite while loop that runs continuously. However, I would like to run SyncRequests() and SyncIncidents() methods in parallel. How do I achieve this?

Comment: put each one on a separate thread. However as @B001ᛦ says having a while (true) loop is bad

Comment: Usually statements like `while (true)` are beeing used for testing (bad habit)... your issue sounds like a xy-poblem

Comment: Answer to this question is: Use Parallel.Invoke()